# Save the sliced images into a different folders in python

Tags: python, image

I am slicing the images into 4 parts and I am saving all the 4 sub-images into one folder. Below is the code I have written. Now, how can I take the entire folder of images one by one, do this operation (slicing) and save the output images (i.e.,4-sub-images) into different folders. I new to python, tried to write this but I am stuck at this point. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

> ```
> from __future__ import division
> from PIL import Image
> from math import ceil
> import os
> import numpy as np
> import glob
>
> image_path = r'/path/to/the/folder'
> count = 1
> for file in os.listdir(image_path):
>     f_img = image_path+"/"+file
>     img = Image.open(f_img)
>     width, height = img.size
>     img = np.asarray(img)
>     X = int(height / 4 )
>     security_band = 50
>     first = img[:X + security_band, :, :]
>     second = img[X - security_band:(2*X) + security_band :, :]
>     third = img[(2*X) - security_band:(3*X) + security_band, :, :]
>     fourth = img[(3*X) - security_band:, :, :]
> Image.fromarray(first).save('Security_Band_v1_{}.png')
> Image.fromarray(second).save('Security_Band_v1_{}.png')
> Image.fromarray(third).save('Security_Band_v1_{}.png')
> Image.fromarray(fourth).save('Security_Band_v1_{}.png')
> count += 1
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at [this document](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html) to become familiar with working with directories and files. Anyway to get all files in a directory you can use `iterdir` as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir), also you can create new directories by [`mkdir` method](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir), and pass your directory + file path to save method.